# Problemas ao inserir dados inteiros no Sybase usando Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5, sybase

Olá,

Estou tendo problemas para inserir valores em tabelas com colunas de tipo de dados inteiro usando Laravel 5.1 e Sybase.

O erro 257 é listado quando a exceção é lançada. Nos manuais do Sybase parece ser um problema de conversão. Eu posso ver que o sql da insert montada pelo framework é algo como

```
 inserir [table_name] ([col1], []) col2 valores ('AAA', '999'))
```

Então, percebo que Laravel está passando todos os valores entre aspas simples, e parece-me que Sybase não aceita este tipo de construção.

Estou usando o Linux Ubuntu com freetds instalado com a versão 5.0 do protocolo.

Alguém já resolveu este tipo de problema? Está faltando alguma configuração ou eu tenho que escrever um driver de extensão para trabalhar com Sybase e Laravel 5.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após várias tentativas de pacotes e drivers verificamos que o problema é o suporte fraco à Sybase pelos drivers PDO aliado à comportamentos do Eloquent que são comuns aos SGBDs que ele suporta nativamente como MySql, Postgres e Sqlite.

Decidimos na equipe por escrever um pacote Eloquente para suporte Sybase e disponibilizar como open-source no Github.

Segue o endereço https://github.com/uepg/laravel-sybase